# Caching result of custom third-party React hook (run hook only once)

Tags: reactjs, caching, react-hooks

I have a third-party hook of which I'd like to cache the result. The hook doesn't allow to define any dependencies and performs a web request (don't focus too much on the web request, it could be anything that returns data asynchronously or performs a heavy calculation inside the hook). Once I have the result of the hook, it won't change (and if it does, I'm okay with using outdated data).

My component and hook basically look like this:

```
const Description = ({ type, id }) => {
  const { description, isLoading } = useDescription(type); // cache `description` dependent on `type`?
  const { data } = useData(id, description);

  if (isLoading) { return <div>Loading {type} {id}...</div>; }

  return (
    <div>{type} {id}: {description}, {data}</div>
  );
};
```

Is it possible to cache each `type->description` combination and not re-execute the hook in an idiomatic React way?

React doesn't allow to execute hooks conditionally, only components (calling hooks) can be rendered conditionally. But how can I cache/memoize `description` here?

The only way I could think of is splitting the component, filling a global cache as a side-effect (making the function impure), and then checking this cache. More or less like this:

```
const cache = {};

const DescriptionData = ({ type, id, description }) => {
  const { data } = useData(id, description);
  return (
    <div>{type} {id}: {description}, {data}</div>
  );
};

const CachingDescription = ({ type, id }) => {
  const { description, isLoading } = useDescription(type);
  if (isLoading) { return <div>Loading {type} {id}...</div>; }

  cache[type] = description; // IMPURE!
  return <DescriptionData type={type} id={id} description={description} />
};

const Description = ({ type, id }) => {
  if (type in cache) { // accessing outside state!
    return <DescriptionData type={type} id={id} description={cache[type]} />
  }

  return <CachingDescription type={type} id={id} />
};
```

This feels so wrong. Is this sensible? Is there a better way? A builtin hook that I missed?

I don't care about race conditions; if the hook is sometimes called 2 times simultaneously, it's no big deal. But assuming that the hook has already completed loading the data once, it shouldn't be loaded again.

TLDR: How to run a custom, third-party hook (conditionally) only once for each distinct argument value? Something like `useCached(() => useDescription(type), [type]);`?

Comment: There are common solutions for this - like redux, lifting state up, or caching libraries like tanstack/query, useSWR, or RTKQuery. I guess it comes down to this: **why** do you want to cache the result? i.e. What behaviour is happening in your application when the result isn't cached that you'd like to avoid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `useCache` hook that stores data on a `Map`, and return the data from the `Map`. If the `Map` doesn't contain the `res` for the `type`, it's a assumed that we're loading. The hook returns the `isLoading` state, the item found in the `Map` (if any), and a function to set items in the cache, and force re-render (by setting a state).

To load the description, render the `LoadDescription` component. When the component loads, the hook triggers, and when the hook returns the response, a `useEffect` sets calls the function to update the cache (`setRes`).

The main component (`Description`) renders `LoadDescription` whenever `isLoading` is `true`.

**Note**: If you need the cache to available globally, you can use the hook in a context.

```
const useCached = type => {
  const [, trigger] = useState(); // used to trigger render
  
  const cache = useRef();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    cache.ref = new Map();
  }, []);
  
  return {
    isLoading: !cache.current?.has(type), // as long as something is not in the cache we need to load it
    res: cache.current?.get(type), // get the data for type
    setRes: useCallback(res => { // update the cache and trigger a re-render
      cache.current?.set(type, res);
      trigger(res);
    }, [])
  };
}

const LoadDescription = ({ type, id, setRes }) => {
  const { description } = useDescription(type);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if(description) setRes(description);
  }, [description, setRes]);
  
  return null;
};


const Description = ({ type, id }) => {
  const { res: description, isLoading, setRes } = useCached(type);
  const { data } = useData(id, description);

  // if is loading render the component to fetch the data
  if (isLoading) return (
    <>
      <LoadDescription 
        type={type}
        setRes={setRes}
        />

      <div>Loading {type} {id}...</div>
    </>
  );

  return (
    <div>{type} {id}: {description}, {data}</div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks. So using a "fake component" is the way to go?

Comment: If the only way to conditionally use a hook is via a component, that's the only solution I can think about.

Comment: I assume `cache.ref` should be `cache.current`? Most hooks seem not to be listing exhaustive dependencies – is that on purpose?

Comment: But after fixing a few issues in the code, it seems to work! I'll give it a few more days before accepting. Thanks already!

Comment: The dependencies are fine. You don't need to include refs or set functions. I've fixed the typo with cache.ref -> cache.current. what other issues?